# Shared data in Textview and maintain State of data can't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I have 5 view which have deferent json data , in all my 5 view i put textview and one done button, if press done button than that view data going on TextView , that is work with its own view but I want to the previous view data show in the current view, and In next view i want both view data and so on (in short user add some data on view 1, view 2 view 3..)

what i really used for it one textview or textview on every view ? how it is possible ? where i store every view data so i can easily access in any view in textview ?

Please give me guide line to achieve that, thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u must use AppDelegate. If u want something from view1 to view2, then combine of view1 and view2 in view3, and so on, u can use global data. Means that everything that u want in all views, define them in appdelegate.

After that a view in which u want that data, access it by use of appdelegate object. This is the best way to use global data with the use of AppDeleg...:)

EDITED:
in AppDeleg.h..

```
NSString *name;
NSString *addr;
```

@property and @synthesize both objects...

Now, use it in view1.m

```
AppDelegate *appDeleg = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.textField1.text = appDeleg.name;
self.textField2.text = appDeleg.addr;
```

This is the simple concept....do it as u want....:)

Comment: can i can do with plist file ??

Comment: But I think u should use ur AppDelegate class. It is the most usable one as my opinion...:)

Comment: ok i will try it but can you tell me that how can i create Appdelegate object ??

Comment: AppDelegate *appDeleg = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

Comment: Define variables(anything u want throughtout ur project)in appdelegate, and use that object with varible name defined in appdelegate...for exa..appDelegate.name, appDelegate.addr ..